# How can I get a percentage to 1 decimal place as a string when I divide two integers?

Tags: c#

Here's what I am using right now:

```
 var pc = (p * 100/ c).ToString();
```

Both p and c are integers but I am not sure how to get the answer as for example something like:

```
 43.5%
```

Would appreciate some advice on what I can do.

Comment: This should be enough for percentage formatting: `pc.ToString("P1")`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to either explicitly cast a value to a non-integer form, e.g. double, or use a non-integer in the calculation.

For example:

```
var pc = (p * 100/ (double)c).ToString();
```

or this (not 100.0 rather than 100):

```
var pc = (p * 100.0/ c).ToString();
```

Next you need to round the result:

```
var pc = Math.Round(p * 100 / (double)c, 1).ToString();
```

But as Tetsuya states, you could use the P1 format string (which would output something like 5.0% - culture dependent - for p = 5, c = 100):

```
var pc = (p / (double)c).ToString("P1");
```